# Why don't arrow functions work in a referenced script in electron?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ecmascript-6, electron, arrow-functions

> Quick Disclaimer: I'm only very vaguely familiar with html and
>   javascript; I never do any web development. I'm learning electron
>   because it seems like a novel approach to gui programming.

---

I'm learning how to use electron while also simultaneously learning different javascript libraries such as jQuery and bootstrap. I'm currently working on jQuery via [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/default.asp). In the [example](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_hide) on the linked page they use anonymous functions to write their script. Cool, but I want to use the arrow function syntax.

Now, I don't know much about their interactive browser environment, but I set up the same example in my own environment. The differences are that I'm using electron to display the page, and I'm linking a script instead of writing it in `index.html`. i.e. under my `head` tag I have

```
 <script src="./script.js"></script>
```

and `script.js` looks like this

```
let $ = require('jquery')

$(document).ready(() => {
    $('p').click(() => {
        $(this).hide()
    })
})
```

`main.js` looks like this

```
const {app, BrowserWindow} = require('electron')
const url = require('url')
const path = require('path')

app.on('ready', () => {
    let win = new BrowserWindow({width: 800, height: 600})
    win.loadURL(url.format({
        pathname: path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'),
        protocol: 'file:',
        slashes: true
    }))
})
```

when I run `electron ./main.js`, you would expext any `<p>` items to disappear when you click them but they don't. However, everything works as expected if I change all the arrow functions in `script.js` back to the old anonymous function syntax.

I don't understand why this is happening because there are arrow functions in `main.js`, and it works completely fine. Is there some extra step I need to do when referencing a script that uses ES6 standard? Or is there something weird going on with electron?

Comment: Is it impossible to use an arrow function to perform an operation on a clicked object then?

Comment: This answered my question and completely solved my problem. I don't know what's the best action: should you answer this so that I can accept it, or should the question be closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/Arrow_functions

Arrow functions, by their definition, do not assign a value to various variables associated with normal functions, one of which being `this`.

*An arrow function expression has a shorter syntax than a function expression and does not have its own this, arguments, super, or new.target*

There are two ways around this issue.  First, use a normal function that will assign the value to `this`.  Alternatively, you can pass in the event to the event handler and access the element off of it.

```
$('p').on('click', e => $(e.target).hide())
```